# vb.net user entered ole db connection string

Tags: database, vb.net, connection-string

I'm new to vb.net and have run into a road block.  I'm making an application that connects to a database with a user entered data connection string.  Trying not to reinvent the wheel, I looked for the vb.net equivalent of 'OLE DB Core Services', the properties menu when editing an .udl file and came up empty handed.  Is there a way to call this service to edit an embedded .udl or resource? or vb.net forms/functions for getting connection string information from the user?

Comment: What you have tried so far? and Why do you want your user to enter connection string?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this article](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/8D4A69C84D352BF58625706C005B48D2):

> to properly configure the UDL properties programmatically
>   would involve a call to the SDK for the Microsoft Host Integration
>   Server. You can use LabVIEW to call a .NET Assembly in order to
>   accomplish this, but this is recommended only for experienced users
>   that are familiar with .NET and ADO-compliant drivers.

May I suggest An alternative solution:

Could you just let the user enter the connection string in an input form of some kind and then use OleDbConnectionStringBuilder to validate and then store the connection string? As [per MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The connection string builders let developers programmatically create
>   syntactically correct connection strings, and parse and rebuild
>   existing connection strings.